# Flask-WTF: how pass structered object to form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

i'm new to python and flask framework.

My problem is I have to make an edit page. So i need to pass all object's exist infos into a form.
Detail:

My object have this kind of structure:

```
class TVChannel(Document):
    __collection__  = 'tvchannels'
    use_dot_notation = True

    structure = {
        '_id'           : basestring,
        'name'          : unicode,
        'streams'       : {
            'city1': { 
                'adapt' : basestring,
                'hds'   : basestring,
                'hls'   : basestring,
                'rtmp'  : basestring,
            },       
            'city2':  {
                'adapt' : basestring,
                'hds'   : basestring,
                'hls'   : basestring,
                'rtmp'  : basestring,
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the view:

```
channel_obj = db.TVChannel().get_id(channel_id) #load a channel's datas into an object from db
channel     = ChannelForm(request.form, obj=channel_obj) #load channel form

return render_template('channel/new.html',form=channel, channel_id=channel_id)
```

The channel_object's "name" they understand and pass it like normal. But the "streams", they did not recognize and pass it to something like this:

```
class ChannelForm(Form):    
    _id         = HiddenField()
    name        = TextField(_('channel name'))    
    streams = {
        'city1': { 
            'adapt' : TextField(_('stream adapt link')),
            'hds'   : TextField(_('stream hds link')),
            'hls'   : TextField(_('stream hls link')),
            'rtmp'  : TextField(_('stream rtmp link')),
        },       
        'city2':  {
            'adapt' : TextField(_('stream adapt link')),
            'hds'   : TextField(_('stream hds link')),
            'hls'   : TextField(_('stream hls link')),
            'rtmp'  : TextField(_('stream rtmp link')),
        }
    }

    submit      = SubmitField(_('Save'))
```

What should i do?
Or is there anyway to modify the way how object's data passed into those parameter of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found this in the documentation and i will use it for now:

in the view:

```
channel_obj = db.TVChannel().get_id(channel_id) #load a channel's infos into an object
channel     = ChannelForm(request.form, obj=channel_obj) #load channel form
channel.CITY1adapt.process_data(channel_obj.streams['City1']['adapt'])
#and others links
```

And in the form:

```
class ChannelForm(Form):    
    _id         = HiddenField()
    name        = TextField(_('channel name'))    
    CITY1adapt  = TextField(_('adapt link')) 
    CITY2adapt  = TextField(_('adapt link'))
    #and so on

    submit      = SubmitField(_('Save'))
```

Now i'm working on when i "save" them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested forms using [wtforms.fields.FormField](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/fields.html#field-enclosures). In your case it would be something like this:

```
class CitiForm(Form):
    adapt = TextField(_('stream adapt link'))
    hds = TextField(_('stream hds link'))
    hls = TextField(_('stream hls link'))
    rtmp = TextField(_('stream rtmp link'))

class ChannelForm(Form):
    _id = HiddenField()
    name = TextField(_('channel name'))
    city1 = FormField(CitiForm)
    city2 = FormField(CitiForm)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. but there's still main problem that i cannot pre-populated the data taken from channelObject.   I mean this code:      channel = ChannelForm(request.form, obj=channel_obj) #load channel form The datas from 'streams' couldn't be passed into form